# Connecting to a Websocket server in FLutter

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, webview

I have built an app with webview to get the cookies when a user login to get the sessionToken value. Now I need to connect to web socket server to receive a message but I can't establish a connection and it seems that maybe I have to use the sessionToken to connect to it.

Here is the sample Cookie

```
[{domain: websiteUrl, expiresDate: date, isHttpOnly: false, isSecure: true, isSessionOnly: null, name: sessionToken, path: /, sameSite: null, value: tokenValue}]
```

I am using flutter 3.19.0 and [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel)
And whenever I try to establish a connection, it immediately goes to *'onDone'* callback.

```
  WebSocketChannel? _channel;
  void connectToWebSocket(String sessionToken) async {
    try {
      _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
        'wss://example.com/socket',
        headers: {'sessionToken': sessionToken},
      );

      _channel!.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          print('Received message: $message');
        },
        onDone: () {
          print('Websocket Closed');
        },
        onError: (error) {
          print('Error $error');
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error connecting to WebSocket: $e');
    }
  }
```

I hope someone could help. Thanks in advance!